# Angular - Sort objects in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have angular objects as below:

```
var objs = {
    "1" : {name:'abc',createdAt:'2016-06-25'}
    "4" : {name:'abc',createdAt:'2015-07-06'}
    "7" : {name:'abc',createdAt:'2015-03-12'}
    "2" : {name:'abc',createdAt:'2016-01-04'}
    "6" : {name:'abc',createdAt:'2016-06-17'}
}
```

i want to sort (orderBy) this **objs** in ng-repeat by property 'createdAt' DESC order.

> Please Note down that objs is of type **Object not Array**.  I am iterating over objects.

how to achieve that?

```
<tr ng-repeat="obj in objs track by $index | orderBy : createdAt : true" >
    <td>{{obj.createdAt}}</td>
</tr>
```

should i use $index or not?

**Here is** [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/4jDXmrBr6SyuGIbZlSaU?p=preview)

Comment: You could use the negative sign (-) in your filter to signify DESC sorting.
`ng-repeat="obj in objs track by $index | orderBy : '-createdAt' " `

Comment: Try without track by: `ng-repeat="obj in objs | orderBy:'-createdAt'"`

Comment: you create an array from this data...and give it to angular the way angular wants

Comment: Rethink your design! It would be better if you sort your object already in the controller.
Otherwise you move logic into the html.

Answer (score 3):

The built-in `orderBy` doesn't work on objects, but someone has created a filter for what you are trying to do:

http://justinklemm.com/angularjs-filter-ordering-objects-ngrepeat/

```
yourApp.filter('orderObjectBy', function() {
  return function(items, field, reverse) {
    var filtered = [];
    angular.forEach(items, function(item) {
      filtered.push(item);
    });
    filtered.sort(function (a, b) {
      return (a[field] > b[field] ? 1 : -1);
    });
    if(reverse) filtered.reverse();
    return filtered;
  };
});


<tr ng-repeat="item in items | orderObjectBy : 'createdAt' : true" >
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/3lbvJCegtHYIougIhK1R?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

If you add order by you will receive an error:

```
orderBy:notarray
Value is not array-like
```

Luckily angular error reference manual will provide following suggestion:

> orderBy must be used with an array-like value so a subset of items can
>   be returned. The array can be initialized asynchronously and therefore
>   null or undefined won't throw this error.
>
> To use orderBy to order the properties of an object, you can create
>   your own array based on that object:

```
  $scope.arrFromMyObj = Object.keys(myObj).map(function(key) {
    return myObj[key];   }); });
```

Full code:

```
<html ng-app="SoApp">
  <head>

  </head>
  <body>
  <table ng-controller="appCtrl">
    <tr ng-repeat="value in data| orderBy:'createdAt':true" >
      <td>{{value.createdAt}}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.6/angular.min.js"></script>
  <script>
    angular.module('SoApp', [])
    .controller('appCtrl', ['$scope',
      function($scope) {
        $scope.objs = {
          "1" : {name:'abc',createdAt:'2016-06-25'},
          "4" : {name:'abc',createdAt:'2015-07-06'},
          "7" : {name:'abc',createdAt:'2015-03-12'},
          "2" : {name:'abc',createdAt:'2016-01-04'},
          "6" : {name:'abc',createdAt:'2016-06-17'}
        };
        $scope.data =  Object.keys($scope.objs).map(function (key) {return $scope.objs[key]});
        console.log($scope.arrFromMyObj )
      }]);
  </script>

  </body>
</html>
```